# NInject to Self instance

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a better way to create a dependency injection to the self instance (not  singleton), than this?

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageLogger
{
    public MainForm(IKernel kernel) : this()
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
        MainForm form = this;
        kernel.Bind<IMessageLogger>().ToMethod((a) => { return form; });
        (...)
```

Just for context: The self instance is a windows forms and I need to listen to certain logger events, created by some controller, in order to properly present them in one textbox or a status bar.

Binding to `.Self()` has a Transient scope and will create a new object for each `.Get()`, using `.ToProvider()` is just a canon to kill an ant, so that leaves me the `.ToMethod()` but I find it awkward to create the `form` temp value in order to be returned.

Comment: What's wrong with kernel.Bind<IMessageLogger>().ToMethod((a) => { return this; }); ?

Comment: @Alex, didn't even tried it because I though that `this` was `that` (anonymous delegates context for me is misleading, since I tend to assume that the context of this was kernel, or something else). So your message for me is accepted. Please add it an answer, and forgive me my dumb question! Thx

Comment: I just took a shot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest answer in history of answers :)

```
kernel.Bind<IMessageLogger>().ToMethod((a) => { return this; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a very simple project, I don't think your form should be implementing `IMessageLogger`. Logically, logging and a window are two completely different things. Here is an option I would recommend:

1. Create a new class that implements `IMessageLogger`.
2. Add an event to `IMessageLogger` that gets raised when a new message is logged.
3. Register this new concrete implementation of `IMessageLogger` with the IoC container.
4. In your form, request the implementation of `IMessageLogger` from the container, and subscribe to the event.
5. When the form sees the event, put the message in a ListBox or whatever.
6. It's probably a good idea to unsubscribe from the event somewhere, like when the form  closes.

It's probably quite possible to simply add a new parameter to your constructor of the `IMessageLogger` type if you're using the IoC container to create your form.

Now, *anything* can display your log messages. The logging facility is now decoupled from your form making maintenance easier in the future, etc. Messages can be logged before the main window opens, too, which might be useful.

Comment: If I wanted to decouple even further, you're right. I'll have producer / consumer, so +1 to your answer. But the intended answer was for presented scenario, and is quite simpler. Thx to @Alex.